# Assign Javascript image object directly to page

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to assign a Javascript image object directly to the DOM? Every example I've seen has the image object being loaded and then the same file name assigned to an HTML element and my understanding is that the actual image data is coming from the browser cache in the filing system.

I want to guarantee that the image is loaded so I want to load it into a Javascript image object have the data in memory and then add it directly to the page.

Is this possible?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the image element and append it directly to the DOM once it has loaded:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
    document.body.appendChild(image);
};
image.src = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/guitar11-hp-sprite.png';
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/H2k5W/3/

Comment: Cool. How about assigning it as the background image of an HTML body?

Comment: @Ian Warburton for background-images, you would have to assign it from the .src, as the backgroundImage property only accepts strings. Like this `document.getElementById('d').style.backgroundImage="url("+image.src+")";`

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function preloader() 
{
heavyImage = new Image(); 
heavyImage.src = "heavyimagefile.jpg";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:preloader()">
<a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:document.img01.src='heavyimagefile.jpg'">
<img name="img01" src="justanotherfile.jpg"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

> http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.images) {
  var preload_image_object = new Image();

  var image_urls = new Array();
  image_urls[0] = "http://mydomain.com/image0.gif";
  image_urls[1] = "http://mydomain.com/image1.gif";
  image_urls[2] = "http://mydomain.com/image2.gif";
  image_urls[3] = "http://mydomain.com/image3.gif";

   var i = 0;
   for(image_url in image_urls) {
     preload_image_object.src = image_url;
   }
}
```