# Only load an image once, then copy to multiple locations?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image

I am writting a little application that displays and plays mp3s in your web browser. At the top I load the album art of all the songs in a playlist. At the bottom of the page I change a single image to match the album art of a song that is currently playing.

The problem is that the album art images are HUGE like `1200X1200` and they take a long time to load each time the song changes.

I was wondering if there was a way to copy the image data and display below instead of just dynamically creating an `img` tag that has to be downloaded each time.

Here is the code that I use to get and display the bottom img:

```
function currentSongInfo() {
    var currentItem = '.jplayer_playlist_current';
    var currentArtist = $(currentItem+' .artist').html();
    var currentSong = $(currentItem+' .thumb-title strong').html();
    var currentAlbumArt = $(currentItem+' img.thumb-image').attr('src');
    //below image is reloaded each time I change it
    currentAlbumArt = '<img src="'+currentAlbumArt+'" />';
    $('#current-song-info-bar').html(currentAlbumArt+'<div><span>'+currentSong+'</span><br>'+currentArtist+'</div>');
}
```

---

Solution provide below by @ali

Added This to my PHP file that gets the image from the MP3:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am missing something in your setup, if the cache-control headers are specified for the image (for the distant future), and the image has been downloaded on the client's browser, the next request for the same image will not result in a new download but will simply pick up the item from the browser's cache (provided the user does not clear the cache for some reason).  You can also look at e-tags - however, in this case, the browser will send a request to the server to check if the item has changed - if it has, download will occur; if not, there will be no download (but at least the http request goes out to check if the item is stale or not).  Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that the reason for why it is loaded and the cached version doesn't just show up, might be that I am not simply using an `img` tag that points to an image in a directory on my server, but I have my image set up like this: `<img src="cover.php?file=blah.mp3" />`. I'm not completly sure, but maybe since I'm using the PHP to get the album art and return it, it forces a reload instead of cache?

Comment: can you check in your browser tools (e.g. in chrome or firefox), how the cache-control headers or e-tags are set for the image resource?

Comment: How do I find where the cache-control headers are in tools?

Comment: if using google chrome - go to tool -> developer tools (ctrl+shift+i), go the network tab, reload the page, click on the image, check the headers (cache-control/e-tags etc should be there).  You can also use something like firefox (firebug)

Comment: I get this for the cache-control: `Cache-Control:max-age=0` Does this mean that it is never cached?

Comment: you need to specify a longer cache-control header value so that the image gets cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ali is correct about the cache. The image will load from cache unless something funny is setup with the response headers or the client. Another way of reusing an image is to create a Javascript image object, like in this post:
[Assign Javascript image object directly to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306371/assign-javascript-image-object-directly-to-page)